# MYSQL combine duplicate rows in left join into one row with all data

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot

I am attempting to format an SQL query using multiple left joins to a readable CSV file. When I do my left joins, it returns multiple rows for the same ID (as it should, because there are multiple non-unique rows being joined with it), however this is not acceptable for a readable CSV file.

What I want is for each duplicate row to be combined into one row with multiple columns for the duplicate data.

Current join results example:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
LEFT JOIN attributes on ID

ID | Name | Attributes
1  | Ken  | Tall
1  | Ken  | Slender
1  | Ken  | Blonde
2  | John | Short
```

Desired results (exported to CSV):

```
ID | Name | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Attribute 3
1    Ken    Tall          Slender       Blonde
2    John   Short
```

I also attempted group by ID, but when I do that it just returns one of the attributes for each ID, which is also not acceptable.

Maybe I'm not looking in the right places but I cannot seem to find any functions to help me accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `GROUP_CONCAT`, no need to know the maximum number of attributes, and ok for csv import.

```
SELECT id, 
       name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(attributes SEPARATOR ';') AS attributes 
FROM people 
GROUP BY id,
         name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use a **conditional aggregation** such as

```
SELECT ID, Name, 
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN attributes END ) AS attribute1, 
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN attributes END ) AS attribute2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN attributes END ) AS attribute3 
  FROM
    (
     SELECT p.ID, Name, attributes,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS rn
       FROM people AS p
       LEFT JOIN attributes AS a
         ON a.ID = p.attribute_ID
     ) AS pa
 GROUP BY ID, Name
```

where `attribute_ID` is a presumed column from the `people` table, and window function is used provided the DB version is `8.0`

Another option would be using dynamic pivot in which no need to know how many distinct attributes for each people and no need to write each conditional for each aggregation for attributes such as

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
           DISTINCT
              CONCAT(
                    'MAX(CASE WHEN rn =', rn,' THEN attributes END) AS attribute',rn
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS rn 
     FROM people 
    ORDER BY rn                 
  ) AS r;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ID, Name, ',@sql,
                   ' FROM
                      (
                       SELECT p.ID, Name, attributes,
                              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS rn
                         FROM people AS p
                         LEFT JOIN attributes AS a
                           ON a.ID = p.attribute_ID
                       ) AS pa
                    GROUP BY ID, Name'); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb28429da1c5efd995418203dbc9c32c)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can also easy use GROUP_CONCAT with SUBSTRING_INDEX like:

```
SELECT p.*, t.name
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.attribs, ',', 1) as attribute1
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.attribs, ',', 2), ',' , -1) as attribute2
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.attribs, ',', 3), ',' , -1) as attribute3
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.attribs, ',', 4), ',' , -1) as attribute4
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT uid, name , CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(attribute),',,,,') as attribs FROM attributes GROUP BY name
) as t ON t.uid = p.uid;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> select * from people;
+----+------+
| id | uid  |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> select * from attributes;
+----+------+------+-----------+
| id | uid  | name | attribute |
+----+------+------+-----------+
|  1 |    1 | Ken  | Tall      |
|  2 |    1 | Ken  | Slender   |
|  3 |    1 | Ken  | Blonde    |
|  4 |    2 | John | Short     |
+----+------+------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT p.*, t.name
    -> , SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.attribs, ',', 1) as attribute1
    -> , SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.attribs, ',', 2), ',' , -1) as attribute2
    -> , SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.attribs, ',', 3), ',' , -1) as attribute3
    -> , SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.attribs, ',', 4), ',' , -1) as attribute4
    -> FROM people p
    -> LEFT JOIN ( 
    -> SELECT uid, name , CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(attribute),',,,,') as attribs FROM attributes GROUP BY name
    -> ) as t ON t.uid = p.uid;
+----+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| id | uid  | name | attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3 | attribute4 |
+----+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |    1 | Ken  | Tall       | Slender    | Blonde     |            |
|  2 |    2 | John | Short      |            |            |            |
+----+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be helpful

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID, Name, Attributes,'Attribute ' || ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) as columns 
   FROM   people) ppl
PIVOT Attributes FOR columns IN('Attribute 1','Attribute 2','Attribute 3'))
ORDER BY ID
```